# What are the Google Spreadsheet event function names?

Tags: google-sheets

Can anyone point me to the documentation defining the specific name of the standard event functions - i.e., onEdit and the like?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the section of the documentation [Understanding Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers), you can find the information requested.

Comment: This still leaves a bit open to question, e.g. nothing about the change event. And, are there any others?

Comment: To expand a bit, here you can find more information [Understanding Events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events)